# RFQ for each supplier selected purchase Request odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

everyone. I am using the purchase request module by ForgeFlow, Odoo Community Association (OCA)
the link https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/purchase_request/
After I create a purchase request and after approval, I will create RFQ its working fine but I can only select one supplier to create RFQ, what I want is to select multiple suppliers and create RFQ for each Supplier just with one click. I have changed the supplier id to Many2many but when I click on create RFQ button an error occurs. How could I do that? as in the image below [image]

Comment: You can override the `Create RFQ` function to handle the many2many field type or create a new function (to call `make_purchase_order` for each supplier) that creates an RFQ for each supplier.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change the code in the module you bought. Something like this works, I've done this before.

```
for supplier in self.supplier_ids:
    order = self.env['purchase.order'].create({'partner_id': supplier.id, 'requisition_id': self.id})
    order._onchange_requisition_id()
```

Just create a new purchase order with partner and requisition_id and call the onchange_requisition_id that all the other values are computed for you.